# C# - Making a BackgroundImage update in real time while editing it in other programs

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, auto-update, viewer

first i have made an desktop AIR app with drag and drop functions to view the tiles image, but because of some issues, i've tryed to make the same in C#. what do you think is the better choice ? ( i know for this little programm performance is not the question, but i mean the dufficulty and complexity of both )

I was building a simple TileViewer, so a picture is selected in openFileDialog and set as tiled BackgroundImage of the Form.

My problem is:

1. I've been using a timer ( interval = 500 ) to reload the image, so if i edit the image in photoshop, the TileViewer will automaticaly reload the updated image ( as i save it in photoshop ).

   BUT the problem is that photoshop doesnt have premissions to do so, cuz the image is opened in an other programm ( my TileViewer )
2. I removed the Timer and made a refresh button instead. but its the same problem.

I thought of making a copy of the bitmap data, but then I get an error that I dont have enought memory for a 32px x 32px img.

My code :

```
    private string FileName;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();

        FileName = "";
    }

    // OPEN FILE btn
    private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg";
        if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            button2.Enabled = true;
            FileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            setImage();
        }
    }

    // REFRESH btn
    private void button2_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        if( FileName != "" ) {
            setImage();
        }
    }

    private void setImage() {
        Bitmap tempImg = new Bitmap( FileName );
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
        PixelFormat format = tempImg.PixelFormat;

        this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap( FileName ).Clone( rect, format );
    }
```

So guys, if you have any suggestions or solutions, let me know.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but instead of a timer, you may want to look at the [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) class.

Comment: yes, i also thought of using that, but first of all i want to fix the premission problem ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update 2:

Another issue was is in line   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);

where in the constructor you should pass the width and heigth of the new image not an arbitary value like 100.

thats why the runtime says that you're out of memory !! (It did for me and I have a 18 GB monster machine)

Update:

your're leaking objects hence the out of memory exception

(Haans Already warned you about disposing objects thats.)

Try the following code

```
private string FileName;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    FileName = "";
}

// OPEN FILE btn 
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg";
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

        FileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        setImage();
    }
}

// REFRESH btn 
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileName != "")
    {
        setImage();
    }
}

private void setImage()
{
Stream str=new FileStream(FileName,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,FileShare.Read);
        Bitmap tempImg= new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromStream(str));
        str.Close();
        using( tempImg)
        {


        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, tempImg.Width, tempImg.Height);

        PixelFormat format = tempImg.PixelFormat;

        this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(tempImg);

        }
}
```

OLD Answer

Like Jason said

you might need to do somethinglike this in your setimage method

```
Stream str = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
   this.BackgroundImage  = Bitmap.FromStream(str);
str.Close();
```

Note that you're better off closing any stream that you open after you use it.

instead of

private void setImage() {
        **Bitmap tempImg = new Bitmap( FileName );   <---**
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
        PixelFormat format = tempImg.PixelFormat;

```
    this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap( FileName ).Clone( rect, format );  
}
```

Comment: i think that solution works fine to me, but i could not test it, there is still the "out of memory" error i get when i click "open" and select an image..., it's still just a 32 by 32 pixel image O.o and it worked fine until i propabbly messed up the code :/ it targetsProgramm.cs -> ' Application.Run( new Form1() );'

Comment: it is the same ! visual studio targets on the last line saying "not enought memory" does it maters if i'm using Visual Studio inside VMware ? ( assigned 2gb's of ram to the vm )
that is really strange , because it is only a very small picture :/

Comment: i've take out the compiled exe and test it on the host system => without errors, so it is Vmware.. anyway, thank you , it seems the right answer for me ^^

Comment: BUT i got still the problem that i dont have premission to override ( with gimp ) the image that is opened in the viewer...

Comment: ahh ok , jeah, i've just passed the 100 for temp. i actually taked the tempImg.width & heigh, lets see if the error dissapears ^^ ( btw. my "monster machine" has also 16GB's of ram, gtx670 phantom 2 should also do all of the graphical work in my games i develop / play ) i was just wondering why this error only occurs in the VM...

Comment: but man, you saved my day :D now it works fine, dont know why the 100 does that crap, but yeah , youre a genius. thak you , and +1 for your support

Comment: @ace oh man ....check now!! I forgot my own advice sorry...check the setimage method now....

Comment: yeah , but i've done that too, still not the solution :/
every other programm ( PS, gimp, paint... ) gives me an error, that it could not override the file ( i bet becouse it's in using by my programm ) i thought of cleaning the openFileDialog... should i just simply set the ofd.FileName to "" ??

Comment: hmm weird ....it works fine for me....are you using the refresh button or timer ??

Comment: still using refresh button..., if u want, i can upload the project files i've so far in a zip file on my server

Comment: it would be nice if you could post your source too, as if you said that it works fine for you ^^

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16580/discussion-between-vivek-bernard-and-ace)

Answer (score 2):

The Bitmap.Clone() method doesn't do what you hope it does.  It creates a "shallow" copy.  You get a new Bitmap object but it still uses the underlying pixel buffer.  Including the memory-mapped file that GDI+ uses to keep the pixel data out of the swap file.  Which in turn puts a lock on the file.

You'll need to make a "deep" copy, do so with the Bitmap(Image) constructor.  Like this:

```
private void setImage() {
    using (var tempImg = new Bitmap(FileName)) {
        this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(tempImg);
    }
}
```

The *using* statement ensures the original image is disposed and the lock gets released.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to open the file manually with ReadOnly flags, and then load the payload of the file into the bitmap by hand.

an alternitive would be to copy the file and then open the copy.

See if you cna run the following code while photoshop has the file open

```
 FileStream s2 = new FileStream(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
```

Comment: if i would make a copy, it yould not update, cuz i'm editing the original, and also save to the original, dont i ?

the problem is not that i cannot open it while other programm is running, the problem is that i can not override it while it is loaded in my programm.

what do you mean with "payload" ? ( sry my englisch is not the best ) i thought of using it like i use a stream reader for text files, like 1. open it, 2. read it & asign it as bg img 3. close it, and repeat the process with timer. does streamReader only works with text files ? or is there a streamreader for img's ? (filestream)

Comment: how do i use FileStream to set this.BackgroundImage = <BITMAP>

Comment: @ace see my answer for using Filestream on a Backgroundimage