# Prevent image from being blocked for overwrite since it is dynamically loaded as background

Tags: c#, image, background, overwrite, blocked

EDIT: also see my older post about this programm to get background informations [C# - Making a BackgroundImage update in real time while editing it in other programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375294/c-sharp-making-a-backgroundimage-update-in-real-time-while-editing-it-in-other)

I've created an image viewer, it displays a chosen image as the background of a 'Form'.

Until I close the program, all images I've loaded in, are blocked from being overwritten with other applications, such as image manipulating apps like Photoshop or GIMP.

My code is pretty simple :

```
public partial class Form1:Form {
    private string FileName;

    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();

        FileName = "";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "PNG Files (*.png)|*.png|JPG Files (*.jpg)|*.jpg";
    }

    private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            button2.Enabled = true;
            FileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            setImage();
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
        setImage();
    }

    private void setImage() {
        Stream str=new FileStream( FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        Bitmap tempImg= new Bitmap( Bitmap.FromStream(str) );
        str.Close();
        using( tempImg = new Bitmap(FileName) ) {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, tempImg.Width, tempImg.Height);
            PixelFormat format = tempImg.PixelFormat;

            this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(FileName).Clone(rect, format);
        }
        openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
    }
}
```

How can I solve this problem ?

UPDATE :

This code doesn't work for me.

```
    private void setImage() {
        // using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("MyImage.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        //var image = Image.FromStream(stream); 
        using( new FileStream( FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read) ) {
            Stream str=new FileStream( FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
            Bitmap tempImg= new Bitmap( Bitmap.FromStream(str) );
            str.Close();
            tempImg = new Bitmap(FileName);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, tempImg.Width, tempImg.Height);
            PixelFormat format = tempImg.PixelFormat;

            this.BackgroundImage = new Bitmap(FileName).Clone(rect, format);
        }
        openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
    }
```

Comment: In your `setImage` you've got `str.Close()` twice...

Comment: my bad, I've just added as i post it. ^^

Comment: Besides that you create `Bitmap` for 3 times!!! What are you doing this for?

Comment: this code was suggested to me in my prev. post -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375294/c-sharp-making-a-backgroundimage-update-in-real-time-while-editing-it-in-other

Comment: I guess you should just follow that answer. It does what you need. Just compare that answer and the code you posted in this question.

Comment: see my update, i've tryed it. it doesn't work..

Comment: By the way, tha answer by Hans Passant works as well, and it's much more simple. You could try to use that

Comment: Delete all your code!!! And copy/paste the code from any answer in the previous post

Comment: They all work, if you change them somehow, they may not...But they **DO** work

Comment: lol, really, yesterday i've just copyed and tryed all the code out, but it does not worked. well it works now, strange O_o thanks anyway

Comment: do not close the stream when using the using keyword.  Coming out of the using, stream will be automatically closed for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("MyImage.png", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
   var image = Image.FromStream(stream);

    // Do something with the image.
}

// The image will not be locked here.
```

Comment: I just tried it,  ran that code and opened paint.net after coming out of the using {} and I was able to edit the image.